# Copy specific row based on a condition Excel

Tags: excel, conditional-statements

[image: I want to do as the following in excel]

I tried the following formula but doesn't work for me :
If(B2=2;A2;"Empty")

Comment: Where did you enter this formula?

Comment: What are you trying to do in column C?  Your formula as of now doesn't work, as there are no `2` values in B.  If `B2` has info, do you want `b2` in `c2`, and if no info, you want `a2`?

Comment: `=if(LEN(B1); B1; IF(LEN(A1); A1; "Empty"))` (that's a *'best guess'* that suits your example)

Comment: Are you trying to evaluate if B2 *contains* 2?  Or actually *equals* 2?

Comment: =IF(B1="Data2",B1,IF(A1="Data1",A1,"Empty"))  In C1, drag down. Just guessing as I'm unsure if that's exactly what you want from your post.

Comment: Yes BruceWayne if column A and B is full copy in C the value of B, if both are empty in C copy empty.

Comment: Thanks @Clusks. Exactly what I wanted

Comment: =IF(B1="Data2",B1,IF(A1="Data1",A1,"Empty")), is it possible to use the content of a cell in place of using B1="Data2"?